# Visual Studio: squash intermediate commits

Tags: visual-studio, git-squash

I can squash the last commits easily with with Visual Studio.
However, if I don't select the latest commit, `squash commits` menu entry is grayed.
Is there a solution with visual Studio to squash intermediate commits?
[image: Visual studio grayed squash commits entry]